# Get return object from another function

Tags: jquery, function, variables

I want to get `formatted_price` and put it in `price` variable

Here is my code:

```
    function woocommerce_price(price) {
        var formatted_price = '';

        var num_decimals    = wc_price_calculator_params['woocommerce_price_num_decimals'];
        var currency_pos    = wc_price_calculator_params['woocommerce_currency_pos'];
        var currency_symbol = wc_price_calculator_params['woocommerce_currency_symbol'];

        price = number_format(price, num_decimals, wc_price_calculator_params['woocommerce_price_decimal_sep'], wc_price_calculator_params['woocommerce_price_thousand_sep'] );

        if ('yes' == wc_price_calculator_params['woocommerce_price_trim_zeros'] && num_decimals > 0) {
            price = woocommerce_trim_zeros(price);
        }

        switch ( currency_pos ) {
            case 'left' :
                formatted_price = '<span class="amount">' + currency_symbol + price + '</span>';
            break;
            case 'right' :
                formatted_price = '<span class="amount">' + price + currency_symbol + '</span>';
            break;
            case 'left_space' :
                formatted_price = '<span class="amount">' + currency_symbol + ' ' + price + '</span>';
            break;
            case 'right_space' :
                formatted_price = '<span class="amount">' + price + ' ' + currency_symbol + '</span>';
            break;
        }

        return formatted_price;         

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("input").change(function(){

            var a = parseInt($('input[name=quantity]').val());
            var price = GET RETURN OBJECT HERE

            $('.amount').html(price+1);

        });
    });
```

**Update**

I changed it to this: https://jsfiddle.net/cp35vh17/

Now it works but still has a problem and that is when I increase the number it's Ok. But when I decrease it , the number increase again

Comment: The function clearly returns a formatted string, not a number, so `.html(price+1)` won't work. It requires an input (the price to format) which you haven't specified, assuming `quantity` isn't price. Anyway, you get the result by calling the function: `woocommerce_price(1234.56)`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `woocommerce_price` function will return a value which name is `formatted_price`, so in order to make it work, **you just need to call your function** with a price value (Since `woocommerce_price` will accept a price value which named as `price`).

So in order to get `formatted_price` you should do as follows:

```js
var price = woocommerce_price(/* price value */);
```

### UPDATE

In order to fix your second issue, you should declare your `price` outside of change event to prevent from creating it each time (When input gets change).

So your code should look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var prices = $('span.amount').text()
  $("input").change(function() {
    var price = '';
    var quantity = parseInt($('input[name=quantity]').val());
    console.log(quantity)
    var price = prices.replace(/[^\d-]/g, '');
    $('.amount').html(price * quantity);
  });
});
```

Comment: the `woocommerce_price` return the price of each product in their single page, but when it do this: `woocommerce_price(100000)` the function doesn't work correctly and just shown 100,000

Comment: @MehranPourjenabi That was just an example for more illustration. You should always provide a value for `woocommerce_price`, otherwise, it won't return any value. Also, `woocommerce_price` won't get price automatically you have to provide that parameter for it. In order to do that, you should first get the price from your page manually like what you did for `quantity` and then pass it as a parameter to your `woocommerce_price`.

Comment: I put the live demo and told the problem in my question

Comment: The code works correctly in jsfiddle but in my own site the price crashed. Could you please see this? http://avinnet-demo.ir/nikorang/fa/product/%d9%86%d8%b1%d9%85%da%a9%d9%86-%d9%87%db%8c%d8%af%d8%b1%d9%88%d9%81%db%8c%d9%84%db%8c/

Comment: That was my mistake, everything is ok. Thank you a lot my freind